# Comparing username and password to data from text file using java

Tags: java, authentication, text-files, java.util.scanner

I want to get datas from text file ordered like

```
qwer,qwer,qwer,qwer,wqer
qwer,qwer,qwer,qwer,wqer
```

But I dont need all data from text file, I just need first 2 data of each line which are username and password. 
Other parts are working fine, just need code for this `loginB` button. `usernameT` `passwordT` are textfields that have been already created.

```
    loginB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       File loginf = new File("login.txt");

            try{
                Scanner read = new Scanner(loginf);
                read.useDelimiter(",");

                while(read.nextLine()){
                    String user = read.next();
                    String pass = read.next();
                     read.next();
                if(usernameT.getText().equals(user) && passwordT.getText().equals(pass) && admin.isSelected()){
                        new Menu();
                    }

                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password");
                usernameT.setText("");
                passwordT.setText("");

                read.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException qwerty){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't find a text file");
            }
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this helpfull:

```
boolean login = false;
while(read.nextLine() !=null){
   String user = read.next();
   String pass = read.next();
   read.next();
   if(usernameT.getText().equals(user) && passwordT.getText().equals(pass) && admin.isSelected()){
      login = true;
      break;                 
   }
}
if(login)
   new Menu();
else {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password");
   usernameT.setText("");
   passwordT.setText("");
}
```